# How do I make a Docker container start automatically on system boot?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Supposed I have a Docker container that I want to run, then I can call

```
$ docker run ...
```

and everything is fine. Is there a built-in way to run a container in a way that it will be restarted automatically, if the system crashes and reboots?

If so, is this also available in Docker Compose?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Yes, docker has [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) such as `docker run --restart=always` that will handle this. This is also available in the [compose.yml config file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/deploy) as `restart: always`.

Comment: This is the first and accepted answer, however probably most of people searching for that feature really want to run their container as a service. The [@kon 's answer using `Systemd` as service manager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39493500/3197383) is one of the best solutions for that purpose and need more upvotes.

Comment: The only problem with this is that "always" will also infinitely restart the container when it was stopped due to an error (see docs). There should be a policy which only starts on daemon-start

Comment: I thought one of the major selling points of containers/docker was that I don't need to install and manage each of my services in systemd (which can be a pain).

Comment: To ensure that docker (and the restart=always services) are started after a reboot, enable the docker service, e.g. `systemctl enable docker`.

Comment: Using docker restart policies has the advantage of cross platform portability. These would run on systems which do not have `Systemd`. Kind of letting Docker handle the interaction with the underlying `init` system, while we operate on a higher level abstraction.

Comment: @lostiniceland Maybe this was improved, but the docs now say it will increase the delay after each failed restart until it hits 1 minute and then give up

Comment: @RémiBecheras beats the purpose as exposed by Mohnish and also, as of 2023, is not recommended as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) _Docker recommends that you use restart policies, and avoid using process managers to start containers._

Answer (score 272):

If you want the container to be started even if no user has performed a login (like the VirtualBox VM that I only start and don't want to login each time). Here are the steps I performed to for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As an example, I installed a oracle db container:

```
$ docker pull alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
$ docker run -d --name=MYPROJECT_oracle_db --shm-size=2g -p 1521:1521 -p 8080:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
$ vim /etc/systemd/system/docker-MYPROJECT-oracle_db.service
```

and add the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start -a MYPROJECT_oracle_db
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 MYPROJECT_oracle_db

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and enable the service at startup

```
sudo systemctl enable docker-MYPROJECT-oracle_db.service
```

For more informations https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/

Comment: For those looking to do this with docker-compose, you can replace the `docker` command above with the `docker-compose` command, using the `-f` flag to specify the location of the docker-compose file: `/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml up`

Comment: To add to what @charlesreid1 said, if your `docker-compose.yml` specifies a `.env` file, use `--project-directory /path/to` **in addition to** explicitly specifying your docker compose file.

Comment: Docker has its log system and process manager. It's unfortunate that it doesn't have the right restart policy.

Comment: Any idea how to do this on Windows Server 2012? I can't run docker unless I login...

Comment: It might also be interesting to some that there's a helpful `[Unit]` directive called `Before=`. Especially when starting things like database management systems, it could be helpful to make sure it's started _before_ specific other services.

Comment: @charlesreid1 - The docker-compose approach appears to suffer from a tty problem, where the containers will immediately stop after starting if you are not running docker-compose from a terminal. More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593396/docker-compose-up-is-starting-the-container-and-immediately-stopping-them

Comment: Full disclosure: Documentation actually states you don't want to do this: "Docker recommends that you use restart policies, and avoid using process managers to start containers." https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: the acceptance answer of using "restart" with docker doesn't get around the issue with the "latest" tag not representing the latest image on a container registry. At least with this answer, you can point it at a shell script that will delete the container and the "latest" tag, and then pull down the latest tag again from the ACR on startup. Useful for VMs that you just want them to always run the latest images when they start up

Comment: @tres Documentation doesn't state that you don't want to do this, it just states that Docker authors recommend their solution instead. Systemd authors, possibly, would recommend using systemd services for all kinds of process management. Does it mean that "you want to do this"? Depends, probably.

Comment: @tres, current docs recommend _not to mix_ Docker restart policies with process managers. So you simply should use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Chances are you are already running docker daemon through systemd. So hoisting individual containers to systemd is kinda redundant. I think that is the rationale behind Docker's recommendation.

Answer (score 249):

The [default restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) is `no`.

For the created containers use `docker update` to update restart policy.

```
docker update --restart=always 0576df221c0b
```

`0576df221c0b` is the container id.

Comment: Doesn't `always` mean the container will restart even if *I* stop it? Surely there is a way to restart a container on reboot without this kind of persistent starting...

Comment: @Marc: no. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/):
`If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted. This is another attempt to prevent a restart loop.`

Comment: Is there a way to start a (series of) conteiner(s) when docker daemon starts, but not to attempt restart on error? I din't find it (using restart policies, of course).

Answer (score 58):

You can use `docker update --restart=on-failure <container ID or name>`.

On top of what the name suggests, `on-failure` will not only restart the container on failure, but also at system boot.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/), there are multiple restart options:

```
Flag            Description
no              Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)
on-failure      Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code.
always          Always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped, it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or the container itself is manually restarted. (See the second bullet listed in restart policy details)
unless-stopped  Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.
```

Comment: Wow good job discovering this, considering it's not mentioned in the documentation. Perfect solution for me.

Comment: One thing to note about using on-failure, if you have a container that depends on another already running, there doesn't seem to be a "start order", so one may start and immediately fail and never start up on OS boot

Comment: This helped me, too, confirmed with `sudo systemctl restart docker`. Well spotted!

Answer (score 51):

To start a container and set it to restart automatically on system reboot use

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped ecstatic_ritchie
```

Where `ecstatic_ritchie` is an example name specifying the container in interest. Use `docker ps -a` to list all container names.

To make particular running containers start automatically on system reboot

```
docker update --restart unless-stopped ecstatic_ritchie
```

To make all running containers start automatically on system reboot

```
docker update --restart unless-stopped $(docker ps -q)
```

See more on Docker [homepage](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

Comment: is there some way to do this in docker compose. Basically i have a docking container i can only seem to start it from docker compose up -d. If i try and start it another way, the sockets don't open properly, i don't know why.

Comment: @Owl in `compose.yml`, you can add `restart: always` to set it's restart policy

Answer (score 27):

1) First of all, you must enable docker service on boot

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker
```

2) Then if you have docker-compose .yml file add `restart: always` or if you have docker container add **restart=always** like this:

`docker run --restart=always`  and run docker container

Make sure

> If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted.

see this [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details) on Docker official page

3) If you want start docker-compose, all of the services run when you reboot your system So you run below command only once

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 12):

More "gentle" mode from the documentation:

```
docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped <image_name>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when the docker daemon is stopped by a reboot, the daemon "stops" the containers, marking them as stopped. Then when the system boots, it doesn't actually start these. It's dumb. Here's the bug: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/652

Comment: The `restart=unless-stopped` option will attempt to start containers when the docker engine is restarted. The exceptions I've seen are when the docker engine itself is not configured to automatically start on reboot (check `systemctl status docker` to be sure it's enabled) and the engine starting containers before networking is ready that I've only seen with overlay networking. Both of these would break `restart=always` too.

Answer (score 8):

You can **run** a container that restart always by:

```
$ docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped <image name OR image hash>
```

If you want to change a running container's configs, you should **update** it by:

```
$ docker update --restart=<options> <container ID OR name>
```

And if you want to see current policy of the container, run the following command before above at the first place:

```
docker inspect gateway | grep RestartPolicy -A 3
```

After all, Not to forget to make installed docker daemon **enable at system boot** by:

```
$ systemctl enable docker
```

To see a full list of restart policies, see: [Restart Policies](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details)

Comment: I'm guessing `gateway` should be the container ID?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to achieve on-boot container startup on Windows.

Therefore, I just created a scheduled Task which launches on system boot. That task simply starts "Docker for Windows.exe" (or whatever is the name of your docker executable).

Then, all containers with a restart policy of "always" will start up.

Comment: Hi @TostMaster, how does it work for you as my containers still go into Exited status on reboot? I'm using docker-compose to start up the containers (about ~10 containers running in a PowerShell script).

Answer (score 4):

This is what crontab is for:

```
@reboot sleep 10 ; docker start <container name> 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t 'docker start'
```

Access your user crontab by `crontab -e` or show it with `crontab -l` or edit your system crontab at `/etc/crontab`

**edit 07-09-2022** This answer should only be used as a backup or alternative to using native Docker restart policies and/or SystemD service units to control container start upon system boot.

I feel like the only reason I mentioned this answer was because of an irrational emotional response due to the over complexity and amount of things you have to get right in order for the SystemD service unit method to work properly because such a simple task should be inherently simple to do on any Linux box.

Comment: What is cron service start before docker service... this would fail in this case...

Comment: @Akhil I understand what you meant. However on most systems with systemd nowadays, crond is configured to start at multi-user.target which is runlevel 2, and docker.service is configured to start After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/running-a-script-during-booting-startup-init-d-vs-cron-reboot

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404667/systemd-service-what-is-multi-user-target

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue running Linux systems.  After the system was booted, a container with a restart policy of "unless-stopped" would not restart automatically unless I typed a command that used docker in some way such as "docker ps". I was surprised as I expected that command to just report some status information.  Next I tried the command "systemctl status docker".  On a system where no docker commands had been run, this command reported the following:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

     Active: inactive (dead)    TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
```

On a system where "docker ps"  had been run with no other Docker commands, I got the following:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

    Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-22 08:33:23 PST; 1h 25min ago

TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com

   Main PID: 3135 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 13

    Memory: 116.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─3135 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
 ... [various messages not shown ]
```

The most likely explanation is that Docker waits for some docker command before fully initializing and starting containers.  You could presumably run "docker ps" in a systemd unit file at a point after all the services your containers need have been initialized.  I've tested this by putting a file named docker-onboot.service in the directory /lib/systemd/system with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
# This service is provided to force Docker containers
# that should automatically restart to restart when the system
# is booted. While the Docker daemon will start automatically,
# it will not be fully initialized until some Docker command
# is actually run.  This unit merely runs "docker ps": any
# Docker command will result in the Docker daemon completing
# its initialization, at which point all containers that can be
# automatically restarted after booting will be restarted.
#
Description=Docker-Container Startup on Boot
Requires=docker.socket
After=docker.socket network-online.target containerd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker ps

[Install]
```

WantedBy=multi-user.target

So far (one test, with this service enabled), the container started when the computer was booted.  I did not try a dependency on docker.service because docker.service won't start until a docker command is run. The next test will be with the docker-onboot disabled (to see if the WantedBy dependency will automatically start it).

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just start `docker.service` itself at boot with `systemctl enable docker.service` than to create a whole other service just to indirectly trigger that service through its socket.

Answer (score 3):

The 2021 answer for this is described very nicely in this [blog post](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2020/09/11/how-to-start-docker-service-at-system-boot/). By default, docker is installed but not enabled. If you're using a recent Ubuntu (e.g., 20) and you installed docker via `apt`, all you have to do is `sudo systemctl enable --now docker`.

That will enable the docker service in systemd and start it right then if it hasn't already started. The docker service doesn't start off enabled when it is installed, but any docker command that uses the docker socket (e.g., `docker ps`) will cause systemd to start the service. Enabling the service will cause it to start at boot time every time.

Comment: downvote but no comment? Was there an error?

Comment: The question was about starting a *container*, not the Docker daemon

Comment: To be fair, the container won't start on boot if the daemon doesn't...

Comment: Thank you — I had set my container to restart but it didn't start on boot until I ran the command you gave (because docker wasn't running on boot)