# docker-compose up is starting the container and immediately stopping them

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build services using docker-compose but containers started using docker-compose is stopping immediately as compose script is over. But when i am creating container using docker run for the same service image it is working.

Here is my compose script:

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
 composetestnetwork:
  driver: bridge
   ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
     - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
       gateway: 172.19.0.1

services:
 composetestdb:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile-testdb
  cap_add:
   - ALL
  container_name: my-db-compose-container
  labels:
   db.description: "This is a test db"
  volumes:
   - c:/Users:/data
  networks:
   composetestnetwork:
    ipv4_address: 172.19.0.5
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  command: 'bash'
```

What can be done to fix this.

Comment: Not sure what you actually did, `docker-compose up` keeps running and shows the logs of the started services. When you stop it the containers will be stopped as well.

Comment: I was just trying to create container through compose and use it.   As far as docker file is concerned...It is correct as I am able to create container from the image and use it through docker run

Comment: When I call docker- compose up ... Logs state service is up.. and after executing entry point script logs state exiting with status code 0

Comment: Why is docker-compose override docker image default command? `command: 'bash'`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you use `bash` as the `command`, but without a terminal, it will exit immediately. This is because when bash starts up, if there is no terminal attached, and it has no script or other command to execute, it has nothing to do, so it exits (by design).

You can either use a different `command`, or attach a terminal with `tty: true` as part of the definition of this service.

```
services:
  composetestdb:
    tty: true
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me but I have to add **stdin_open: true** along with **tty: true**

Comment: sir, I just want to tell you that I love you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but `tty : true` doesn't resolve the problem for me.

This is my docker-compose file :

```
---
version: "3"
services :
  data:
    container_name: data
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0283
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./database:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  mail:
    container_name: mail
    image: djfarrelly/maildev
    ports:
      - "1080:80"
      - "1025:25"
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: "web:php7.1a"
    links:
      - mail
      - data
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./www:/var/www/html"
    working_dir : /var/www/html
    tty: true
    command:
      echo "test"
      #bash -c "php composer.phar self-update"
```

After `command`, Docker return me : "the container is exited (0)"
If I comment these lines, the container starts fine.

```
Windows 10 Pro
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
Docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm running the same and getting the same behavior. Any luck so far?

Comment: I had this issue with version 3.4, changing to a different version resolved this.

Answer (score -3):

I think if no process keeps the container alive then it stops.

You could add an infinite loop (as a workaround) to your service in your docker file so it stays up:

```
command: sh -c "while true; do sleep 3600; done"
```

Comment: There's not usually a benefit to having a container running a sleep loop; if this seems like the right answer, just deleting the container definition might be better.