# How to start docker container process after restart machine?

Tags: docker, process, containers

If start a docker container like:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

It can be seen when run

```
docker ps
```

But after restart machine and run `docker ps` again, it can't been found.
When check `docker ps -a` can see it exist.

How to week it up at this case if don't want to kill this process to run a new one?

Comment: This might help I think. https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: @H.Hakvoort Yes, I think you gave a right way: `docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped ...`. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a Docker container start automatically on system boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449313/how-do-i-make-a-docker-container-start-automatically-on-system-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers don't start automatically on system boot because the Docker default restart policy is set to no.

To achieve that you shoud do:

```
docker update --restart=always <container ID or name>
```